# Insert image in jspdf stopping pdf from generating

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, pdf, razor-pages, jspdf

I'm creating a Razor Pages Web App and I'm trying to have a button that when clicked, generates a pdf. To do this, I'm using jsPDF to convert html to pdf. I was able to get it to create and open a pdf, but when I try to add an image, I run into the problem that clicking the button doesn't  any pdf. I was able to create the image-less pdf with the following code:

Code for button:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary order-button" id="testImage" onclick="this.form.submit(@Model.Project.ID)">Create Image</button>
```

Code in Scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var specialElementHandlers = {
                '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            $('#testImage').click(function () {
                var doc = new jsPDF();
                doc.fromHTML($('#testImagePDF').html(), 15, 15, {
                    'width': 170,
                    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                });

                //THIS IS WHERE I WAS PUTTING THE IMAGE

                doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
                doc.save('TestImage_' + document.getElementById('testNum').value + '.pdf');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Html for testImage:

```
<form method="post" hidden>
    <div id="testImagePDF">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.5.6/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js"></script>
        <header style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000">
            <h2 style="margin:0; padding:0">Test Image</h2>
        </header>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I add the following code to the spot commented in the scripts code, the pdf no longer opens after clicking the button:

```
//Code to insert the image
var line = new Image();
line.src = 'BlackRectangle.jpg';
doc.addImage(line, 'jpg', 10, 10, 80, 40);
```

The image 'BlackRectangle.jpg' is located in my wwwroot folder in my project. Does anyone know why after adding the image my pdf will not open and/or how to fix it so it opens and displays the image?

Notes: -This is in a Razor page's 'Details' page (created with CRUD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you press `f12` in the browser, you will find the error. The image path is not correct.

Add a "/" before the image.

```
line.src = '/BlackRectangle.jpg';
```

Comment: Ouch, that's a blunder! Thank you so much mj1313! I was stuck on that for so long...